# Can qemu-img uncompress qcow2 file?

Tags: virtual-machine, qemu, qcow2

We can use the `-c` option for `qemu-img` to compress the qcow2 file, e.g., [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/432119/is-there-any-way-to-shrink-qcow2-image-without-converting-it-raw), but at the cost of uncompressing it while using. Suppose I am given a compressed qcow2 file, does qemu-img have any option or command to uncompress this qcow2 file? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it can.

Use `qemu-img convert` with the `-O raw` option (or `-O qcow2` **without** the `-c` compression option).  e.g.

```
qemu-img convert -f qcow2 -O raw input.qcow2 output.raw
```

or

```
qemu-img convert -f qcow2 -O qcow2 input.qcow2 output.qcow2
```

Comment: So, if I want to keep the qcow2 format, do I have to convert again from raw to qcow2? Is qemu-img able to uncompress directly from qcow2 to qcow2?

Comment: RE: "but at the cost of uncompressing it while using" - depending on the size and compression used, reading and uncompressing a compressed file is usually faster than just reading uncompressed data.   CPUs are fast and powerful, while disk I/O is slow (even on a PCI-e Gen 4 NVME drive).

Comment: You could use `-O qcow2` without the `-c` option if you wanted to retain the benefits of qcow2 (like snapshots).     Personally, I use either compressed qcow2 files or ZFS zvols (with compression enabled).....and use `qemu-img` to convert between them if I need to.